# DataGridView Control with Grouping Capabilities

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I've seem some other posts regarding datagrids that allows grouping. I've downloaded the DevExpress DataGrid for Windows Forms but it really looks complicated. I actually need a Datagrid that derives from DataGridView as a lot of my data binding is code driven and uses the DatagridView classes.

I've managed to find this OutLookgrid on CodeProject, I was wondering if anyone used this before?

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/OutlookGrid.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've downloaded the DevExpress
>   DataGrid for Windows Forms but it
>   really looks complicated.

Looking really complicated and being really complicated are not the same thing. I use the DX XtraGrid everyday and I can assure you its as complicated as:

```
gridControl1.DataSource = myDataTable;
```

.. if you want just a standard grid out of the box.

Comment: Very true. The difference between GridView and GridControl can be confusing at first. XtraGrid has grouping, filtering and many other features that enrich your app so quickly ...